# keeping the formatting on a fillin field

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, text-formatting

I created a Word 2013 template, with a fillin field with references (`{SET module {FILLIN "What Module do you want to install?"\o}}`). Some of the reference locations have underlined formatting `{REF module \*MERGEFORMAT}`. On those locations, I have the 'preserve formatting during updates' checkbox marked. If I use one word in the fillin response, it underlines fine. However, if the answer has two words, only the first one is underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change \*MERGEFORMAT to \*CHARFORMAT

\*MERGEFORMAT works on a "run by run" basis. It isn't usually what you need if you want to apply a single format to the whole field.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you underlined the text in the field result only. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to show the field code and then underline the entire sentence there.

Comment: I did verify that the whole section was already underlined (with alt + F9).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my side, can you scrub and attach your document which demonstrates the problem somewhere?

Comment: here's a link to the file. Thanks for the help

http://dropcanvas.com/nvqly